# R Shiny busy spinner in flexdashboard OCR

Tags: r, shiny, tesseract, flexdashboard

I'm building a little app for OCR.

depending on the image, sometimes teseract takes some time to compute. While it's taking its time, I'd like to add a little spinner saying loading or computing algo.

Here's a simplified extract of my code:

````
---
title : app demo
author : yeshipants
output : 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    self_contained : TRUE
    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = FALSE)
```


```{r loadPackages}
setwd("C:/Users/y_bho/Desktop/Training/OCR")
library(magick)
library(tesseract)
```

Column {.sidebar data-width=350}
-------------------------------------
### Input & Parameters
```{r inputImages, cache = TRUE}

selectInput("imagesToChoose", 
            label = "Choose an image to process",
            choices = c("Language example 1", 
                        "Language example 2",
                        "Jounal example"),
            selected = "Language example 1") 
```

Row {.tabset}
-------------------------------------  

### Image
```{r displayImage, cache = FALSE}    
renderImage({      
  if (input$imagesToChoose == "Language example 1"){
    list(src = "images/receipt.png", height = 240, width = 300)
  }
  else if(input$imagesToChoose == "Language example 2"){
    list(src = "images/french.JPG", height = 240, width = 300)
  }
  else if(input$imagesToChoose == "Jounal example"){
    list(src = "images/journal.jpg", height = 240, width = 300)
  }    
}, deleteFile = FALSE)

```

### OCR
```{r}
# load the dictionary

imageInput <- reactive({
 if (input$imagesToChoose == "Language example 1"){
    x = "images/receipt.png"
  }
  else if(input$imagesToChoose == "Language example 2"){
    x = "images/french.JPG"
  }
  else if(input$imagesToChoose == "Jounal example"){
    x = "images/journal.jpg"
  }
  return(x)
})

eng <- tesseract("eng")

text <- reactive({
  tesseract::ocr(imageInput(), engine = eng)
})

renderPrint({
  cat(text())
})

```
````

Basically between the user choosing different images, I want to display "loading" until tesseract is working on the reactive function at the bottom of the code.

I've seen the busy indicator busyIndicator(wait = 1000) in [this repo](https://github.com/AnalytixWare/ShinySky)
but, first, the package isn't downloading, and second, i don't know where to place it, especially within a flexdashboard.

**EDIT**

All the while preserving the output obtained from cat(text()).
Example; if I want to perform an OCR on the below receipt :

[image: receiptImage]

I'd need this output (to capture line by line information):

[image: receiptOutput]

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a flexdashboard with a busy indicator spinner:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    includes: 
      after_body: "busy.html"
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Waiting time between eruptions and the duration of the eruption for the
Old Faithful geyser in Yellowstone National Park, Wyoming, USA.

```{r}
selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
            choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20)

sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
            min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
```

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Geyser Eruption Duration

```{r}
plotOutput("plot")
output[["plot"]] <- renderPlot({
  Sys.sleep(5) # simulates a time-consuming task
  hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
       xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser Eruption Duration")
  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
})
```
````

The file **busy.html**, in the same folder:

```html
<style>
  .busy { 
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(230,230,230,.8);
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
</style>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#plot").on("shiny:recalculating", function(e){
      $(".busy").show();
    }).on("shiny:recalculated", function(e){
      $(".busy").hide();
    });
  });
</script>

<div class = "busy">
  <img src = "https://loading.io/spinners/comets/lg.comet-spinner.gif"/>
</div>
```

[image]

So for your case, I would try something like that (I have not tried):

````
```{r}
# load the dictionary
imageInput <- reactive({
 if (input$imagesToChoose == "Language example 1"){
    x = "images/receipt.png"
  }
  else if(input$imagesToChoose == "Language example 2"){
    x = "images/french.JPG"
  }
  else if(input$imagesToChoose == "Jounal example"){
    x = "images/journal.jpg"
  }
  return(x)
})

output[["tesseract"]] <- renderPrint({
  eng <- tesseract("eng")
  tesseract::ocr(imageInput(), engine = eng)
})

textOutput("tesseract")
```
````

and in **busy.html**, replace the script with:

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tesseract").on("shiny:recalculating", function(e){
      $(".busy").show();
    }).on("shiny:recalculated", function(e){
      $(".busy").hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```

(and don't forget `after_body: "busy.html"` in the YAML header).

---

## EDIT

I have tried your flexdashboard now. If you want to use the reactive conductor `text`:

```r
eng <- tesseract("eng")

text <- reactive({
  tesseract::ocr(imageInput(), engine = eng)
})

output[["tesseract"]] <- renderPrint({
  cat(text())
})
textOutput("tesseract")
```

then it's better to do:

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tesseract").on("shiny:outputinvalidated", function(e){
      $(".busy").show();
    }).on("shiny:recalculated", function(e){
      $(".busy").hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer Stephane. I'm having 2 issues. 
First, when I'm replicating the geyser example (with busy.html created with notepad in same folder), I get a little blue box with a question mark in it.
And second, I have my own spinning loading .gif file in my folder. 
How to use that one instead of the html link from busy.html?

Comment: Hello @Yeshyyy. You get this blue box because you visualize in the Rstudio viewer; You have to open the dashboard in the browser. For your gif, try to put it in the `www` subfolder of the dashboard, and do `<img src = "yourspinner.gif"/>`.

Comment: sorry www folder?

Comment: @Yeshyyy Create a www subfolder of the folder containing the Rmd file, and put the gif into it. If that doesn't work, try to just put in the same folder.

Comment: great! they both work. 
my flexdashboard is working now with the spinner.
One thing though, I can't render as text. Otherwise the output is all on the same line. I need the output in the same 'format' as the photo, therefore I use cat(text). What would be the fix for that? I tried uiOutput("tesseract") instead of textOutput but it doesn't work

Comment: @Yeshyyy I don't understand. You can do cat(text).

Comment: the output i get from your solution is not as in the EDIT, but it's like the new image I just added (in the EDIT again.)

Comment: @Yeshyyy So change `text` to `cat(text)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189375/discussion-between-yeshyyy-and-stephane-laurent).

Comment: @Yeshyyy Indeed, you're right. Try to use `renderText` instead of `renderPrint`, without `cat`, and use `verbatimTextOutput` instead of `textOutput`.

Comment: I used renderPrint & verbatimTextOutput :) it worked perfectly. renderText didn't show any output in the app. Thank you so much Stephane!